# Fix settlement crack between ceiling and wall

Tags: ceiling, caulking, crack, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

I’m fixing up around our house and am tackling this issue. I have a solid crack where my wall, kitchen ceiling, and angled living room ceiling all meet. Looks like someone last used a whole lot of caulk to fill it, but I’m looking for a better solution. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: There are _many_ similar questions on this site. Did you search? The bottom line is that there's seasonal movement there, and the only permanent fix will be an expansion joint.